# Percentage by group - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, average

I have this sample.

[image]

What I need is getting an average per key not key and value. However, the syntax I used appear to give me the average per key and value.

```
select avg(value2),KEY,VALUE from testavg
GROUP BY key,value
order by key, value
```

Doing otherwise will yield a syntax error. The results I need are as follow:

```
10 A 0.96
10 B 0.04
12 C 1
```

But the statement I used yields the incorrect results above.
Could this be achieved by issuing 1 single oracle select statement?  I have included the statement to create the entire table.

```
CREATE TABLE "TESTAVG" 
       (    "KEY" NUMBER, 
        "VALUE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
        "VALUE2" NUMBER
       ) 

Insert into TESTAVG (KEY,VALUE,VALUE2) values (10,'A',12);
Insert into TESTAVG (KEY,VALUE,VALUE2) values (10,'A',13);
Insert into TESTAVG (KEY,VALUE,VALUE2) values (10,'B',1);
Insert into TESTAVG (KEY,VALUE,VALUE2) values (12,'C',20);
```

Comment: how are you getting an average of .96 from 2 values of 12 and 13 for the "10,A" group ??

Comment: Then just remove value from the query.

Comment: You can exlude value from your query and group by key. That's what you ask for I guess. Select avg(value2),key from testavg group by key

Comment: OldProgrammer/Oguz: Unfortunately he goes on to show the results he expects .. which appear to be grouped by Key + Value .. O.o  And the results don't make much sense.  Not really sure what he wants yet. :(

Comment: 0.96 and 0.04 are coming from where???

Comment: @Ditto Yes you are right, but the desired output and the question described based on the reference table does not match. So, I believe OP didn't give proper explanation.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: and Ditto: 10, A, (12+13)/(12+13+1)=0.96,  10,B,1/(12+3+1)=.04, I would like to group by Key. Hope that clarify my question. To OldProgrammer: I would like to include Value in the row to show the value corresponding to the average as well

Comment: Revise your question, and describe your formula as variable.

Comment: To All: Thank you very much for your response. Let me revise my question. What I need is to get a prorated of the value2 by the key and value. I apologize for my English.

Comment: Apologies for Ditto and Ankit. I got mixed up between the average and percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    select avg(value2),KEY from testavg
    GROUP BY key
    order by key;

8.66666666666666666666666666666666666667    10
20                                          12
```

EDIT: Specs are still not clear but this might be what you need...

```
with gr1 as (select key,sum(value2) sumvalue
            from testavg
            group by key)
,    gr2 as (select key,value,sum(value2) sumvalue
             from testavg
             GROUP BY key,value)
select gr1.key,gr2.value,gr2.sumvalue/gr1.sumvalue
from gr1
,    gr2
where gr1.key = gr2.key;


10  B   0.0384615384615384615384615384615384615385
12  C   1
10  A   0.9615384615384615384615384615384615384615
```

Comment: Did you see desired results?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't match the output he says he's expecting.  It's the obvious answer based on his first part of question, but he goes on to contradict himself. :(

Comment: OP: What I need is getting an average per key not key and value. And that's what this is.

Comment: I agree with @RobertMerkwürdigeliebe, I guess OP didn't give proper values on the reference table in the question.

Comment: @RobertMerkwürdigeliebe: Thank you for the response. This is the calculation 10, A, (12+13)/(12+13+1)=0.96,  10,B,1/(12+3+1)=.04

Comment: Where are those numbers coming from?  (12+3+1) ?? there is no 3 in your sample data set ??

Comment: @user1205746 Please revise your question. Calculations above do not match specifications in the original question

Comment: @Ankit - good guess, let's let OP confirm that - if that's the case, the solution's pretty simple :)

Comment: @RobertMerkwürdigeliebe: Thank you for straighten me up. It is actually a percentage not an average. I got mixed up between the percentage and the average. I have corrected the expected results.

Answer (score 4):

This query might run faster on larger data - only reads the table once:

```
  select distinct key, value,
         sum(value2) over (partition by key, value) / sum(value2) over (partition by key)  r
   from testavg
  /

         KEY VALUE                         R
  ---------- -------------------- ----------
          10 A                    .961538462
          10 B                    .038461538
          12 C                             1
```